# Can the same cluster be found at different (nonconsecutive) iterations of k-means?

Tags: clustering, k-means

During a k-means process, could a cluster at iteration `t` be found identical to iteration `t+h` with `h` strictly greater than 1. By "identical" I mean that the points containing in the cluster are the same. The distance used during the process is not necessarily the Euclidean distance. I am not talking about a cluster that remains unchanged during several consecutive iterations.

Comment: "The distance used during the process" which distance do you mean? Between a point and a cluster centre?

Comment: So you mean a cluster that at one iteration is formed, then it breaks up / is merged with (by at least one element) with other clusters, then it reforms?

Comment: @ttnphns That's it exactly. I'm talking about the distance used between a point and the centroid during the assignment phase.

Comment: @jbowman Exactly. Let's take an example of a cluster containing 4 points with indices 2,6,8 and 11 in iteration 3. At iteration 4 the points 8 and 11 leave the cluster while the points 2 and 6 remain. At iteration 7 points 8 and 11 return to form the cluster again containing only points 2, 6, 8 and 11 as in iteration 3.

Comment: Intuitively, I presume it is possible with k=3+ clusters with some datasets with noisy clusters. Centroids may crawl to and fro in all directions to pick cases formerly in another cluster. So after a while, a specific cluster may find itself with the same points as once earlier, but now the _other_ clusters have improved since that time. Minimization of SSw monotoniccally improves for all data together, but not necessarily for each cluster separately.

Comment: @ttnphns Thank you for your response. I need to show that fact. Do you know how I could generate the data sets to see this fact. And if a precise distance is required in this case. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with k=3+ clusters with some datasets with noisy clusters. Centroids may crawl to and fro in all directions to pick cases formerly in another cluster. So after a while, a specific cluster may find itself with the same points as was once earlier, but now the *other* clusters have improved since that time. Minimization of $SS_{within}$ monotonically improves for all data together (the pooled quantity), but not necessarily for each cluster separately.

I coded a simulation, to check this possibility, and after 25 min of rerunning it (few hundred random datasets screened) I came across one which shows the phenomenon of a cluster returning to its previous state after a while of being different.

The data and their cluster memberships after each iteration of K-means procedure (k=4, classic k-means with euclidean point-centre distance) from iteration 1 through iteration 5:

```
              v1               v2   it1   it2   it3   it4   it5

 .84831138327718  .58140401635319     4     4     4     4     4
 .67106797685847  .88460275391117     4     4     4     4     2
 .58080859528854  .98642699280754     2     2     2     2     2
 .15771444793791  .43305730633438     2     2     2     1     1
 .09272580547258  .57030820799991     3     3     3     3     3
 .16485541546717  .97212406387553     3     3     3     3     3
 .22708307392895  .68468635436147     3     3     3     3     3
 .18495378037915  .80158332362771     3     3     3     3     3
 .97531639086083  .57562120864168     4     4     4     4     4
 .77217109594494  .72062013112009     4     4     4     4     4
 .43300260324031  .79979852680117     2     2     2     2     2
 .36852580914274  .20432187523693     1     1     1     1     1
 .37565710442141  .88585085840896     2     3     3     3     2   point 13
 .79730158345774  .24956722324714     1     1     1     1     4
 .84813683293760  .47188163083047     4     4     4     4     4
 .73653845069930  .14241099823266     1     1     1     1     1
 .55498108407483  .78972943872213     2     2     2     2     2
 .35882399510592  .94787727808580     3     3     3     3     3
 .64057727577165  .57834829110652     4     4     4     4     4
 .09238714771345  .32185426680371     2     1     1     1     1
 .50533355493099  .94762891158462     2     2     2     2     2
 .44944926491007  .15070246625692     1     1     1     1     1
 .60101841390133  .68216031696647     4     4     4     4     2
 .78959528077394  .27253311593086     1     1     1     4     4
 .44872076110914  .45834432216361     2     2     2     2     1
 .30981802893803  .54649883462116     2     2     2     2     2
 .57883600518107  .11959085566923     1     1     1     1     1
 .49890118604526  .69091068347916     2     2     2     2     2
 .19405315909535  .28219770686701     1     1     1     1     1
 .53718406055123  .18184986338019     1     1     1     1     1
 .26158903818578  .96129645407200     3     3     3     3     3
 .28288467554376  .30816435487941     1     1     1     1     1
 .43996903160587  .66844457481056     2     2     2     2     2
 .85048272693530  .17229161178693     1     1     1     1     4
 .59549544705078  .63707443280146     4     4     4     4     2
 .00930084241554  .68682220485061     3     3     3     3     3
 .74380696704611  .59401515033096     4     4     4     4     4
 .71935363346711  .37996421288699     4     4     4     4     4
 .00247879372910  .01783720077947     1     1     1     1     1
 .17840382410213  .35162133490667     2     2     1     1     1
```

The initial centres used for this analysis:

```
cluster                v1               v2

       1  .85048272693530  .17229161178693
       2  .43300260324031  .79979852680117
       3  .16485541546717  .97212406387553
       4  .74380696704611  .59401515033096
```

Plots demonstrating clusters after each iteration (after iteration 1, points has been already once reassigned to the updated centroids). Cluster 3 is again the same after iteration 5 as it was after iteration 1. Point 13's travelling was the cause of it in this example. While one specific cluster (3) returned to its earlier state, the other clusters progressed to change since then:

[image]

Cluster situation after iteration 1 vs iteration 5:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to experiment and writing this reply. So the hypothesis of finding the same cluster non-consecutively is true in these experiments. Does this fact occur rarely? I see it doesn't happen very often.  Can it occur significantly in some particular datasets and/or particular point-centroid distances?

Comment: It looks like to occure not often indeed, and it depends on the data. This particular phenomenon does not seem strange or very interesting. I think it can happen with any versions of k-means.